# Web Api и Asp.Net MVC клиент

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Сделал в учебных целях Asp.Net MVC приложение ресторан.

Функционал: прием продуктов, списание продуктов, продажа блюд(списание продуктов на основе рецептов проданных блюд), передача продуктов между ресторанами.

Теперь хочу попробовать сделать по существующей модели WPF-приложение и позже SPA на Angular.

Решил сделать Web API, чтобы все три клиента обращались к базе данных через него. Опыта написание Api до этого не было.

Если я буду переделывать MVC приложение я должен буду где-то в настройках прописать адрес API? В контроллерах я буду вызывать методы API, получать json,генерировать на основе его viewModel и отправлять во view?

Еще есть идея чтобы классы viewModel для MVC и WPF сделать общими.
Также сделать какую-то библиотеку для обертки APi методов или лучше сделать один класс для вызова всех методов, чтобы в MVC добавить внедрение зависимости?

В правильном направление я думаю?

Comment: "Еще есть идея чтобы классы viewModel для MVC и WPF сделать общими." - для WPF во вьюмодел нужно будет использовать команды реализующие интерфейс `ICommand`, для вывода в UI изменяющихся свойств потребуется реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Так что такая идея создания общих вьюмоделей для WPF и MVC вряд ли представляется разумной.

Answer (score 2):

> Если я буду переделывать MVC приложение я должен буду где-то в настройках прописать адрес API? В контроллерах я буду вызывать методы API, получать json,генерировать на основе его viewModel и отправлять во view?

Чтобы иметь возможность добавлять `api-контроллер` в уже **имеющийся** MVC-проект, проделайте шаги описанные [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project), а именно:

1. Через NuGet установите `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`;
2. Добавьте класс `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` с определением `api-маршрутов`, со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
       }
   }
   ```
3. В файле `Global.asax.cs` необходимо вызвать регистрацию `api-маршрутов` первее `mvc-маршрутов`. Для этого сделаем вызов `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)` перед `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`;

---

Теперь, говоря в рамках SPA-приложения, после того как мы настроим маршрутизацию в модуле AngularJS (например):

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

exampleApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider    
        .when('/example', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/example.html',            
            controller: 'exampleCtrl'
        })

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

мы можем (например) перейти на `example.html` с помощью вызова `<a href="#/example">Example</a>`